# MKLocalSearch doesn't provide the same results as search in native Apple Maps app

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

When I search in MKLocalSearch and Apple Maps using the same string I get different results, usually in Apple Maps I get a lot of different locations but in MKLocalSearch I get only one.

Apple Maps:

[image]

My app using MKLocalSearch:

[image]

In both cases I was searching being in Berlin and in MKLocalSearchRequest I set .region property of Berlin region

Which services does Apple use for their location search?

Comment: Man, you answered my 4 years old question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101240/how-to-get-same-search-hints-as-apple-maps-in-my-application Thank you very much :)

Comment: @travdu Oh, it seems i couldn't find your question at that time...
This issue really took my a while to find the solution

Comment: is it working for you as expected? I didn't have time to try it so far :)

Comment: yes, that works perfectly. it will provide results like these: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62d15497f74bf29a99249a12181b717a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some searching I've investigated that [MKLocalSearchCompleter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter) is the class that Apple uses in their Map app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101240/how-to-get-same-search-hints-as-apple-maps-in-my-application you are my hero now !