# Different search results between Apple Map and MKLocalSearch

Tags: ios, mapkit

When I do a search for nearby restaurants using **MKLocalSearch** with a region of 1000 meters in radius, I get results that could be out of range by a few kilometers. Below is how I set the range in swift:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.033671, 121.564427)
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 1000, 1000)
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurant"

let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
localSearch.start(completionHandler: ...)
```

The returned results are different from what you get with the "Search Here" button inside **Apple Maps** app.

In **Apple Maps** app, when searching for keywords such as "restaurant", there appears a button "Search Here" on the bottom where you could search nearby places, and the listed items are somewhat different from what I get with **MKLocalSearch**.

So my question is how to get similar search results as that of **Apple Maps** with **MKLocalSearch**?

Comment: I thought this question could refs to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249382/mklocalsearch-doesnt-provide-the-same-results-as-search-in-native-apple-maps-ap