# Alamofire Swift 2 - cannot submit for beta testing (Xcode 7 GM)

Tags: cocoapods, swift2, testflight, alamofire, xcode7

I have followed the instructions on installing the [swift2 branch of Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0) with cocoa pods. The app works well in the simulator, however, when I archive it for submission with Xcode 7 GM I receive an email with an error:

"The bundle contains an invalid implementation of Swift. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or pre-release tools"

This issue definitely relates to the framework as without it I am able to submit for beta testing with the same version of Xcode. I have tried turning bit code OFF in the build settings for Alamofire but it does not help.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My podfile links only against Alamofire framework:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

One of the things that I found rather strange is that when I try to submit an archive I have the following screen:

[image]

Maybe this can be helpful in identifying the issue. The extra two targets are notification centre widgets. Disabling them doesn't resolve the issue. And without Alamofire I am able to submit for beta testing with both widgets attached.

## Update

For those who are suggesting that "Swift 2.0 is in beta so you cannot submit" I want to clarify once more - **I am trying to submit for beta testing**. And **YES**, it is possible!

As I have indicated, I am able to submit for beta testing if I remove Alamofire and my own app is written in Swift 2.0. And if someone still thinks that "it is not possible" [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=ios%209%20testflight) is some info for you. Please read it first before posting comments or down voting question.

## Update 2

This issue is still there with Xcode 7 GM...

Comment: Could you post your Podfile so we know what else you are trying to link against? Also, for clarification purposes, if you remove Alamofire as a dependency, are you able to submit your app?

Comment: @cnoon I link only against alamofire in my podfile. Updated my question to include it. Yes, without framework I am able to submit for beta testing without problems

Comment: @DavidSkrundz I am not submitting to the App Store. I am submitting for beta testing. Please read the question carefully. And, as I have indicated, it is possible to submit Swift 2.0 apps for beta testing.

Comment: @DavidSkrundz I am sorry, but can you read the question? i have clearly indicated that removing Alamofire fixes the issue and I am able to submit my app for beta testing. If you are registered as a developer you should have received an email about a month ago from Apple where they explained that you are now able to submit your iOS 9 apps for beta testing

Comment: @DavidSkrundz here is some info for you: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=ios+9+testflight . Sometimes it is helpful to first research the topic and only then to write something on it

Comment: @cnoon I have included another screenshot. When I try to submit my app I have a rather strange screen appearing showing Alamofire as one of the targets (the other 3 are my app and 2 extensions which go with it). Maybe it can be helpful

Comment: What are the extensions and what happens if you disable them?

Comment: @cnoon these are 2 widgets for the notification centre. I haven't tried disabling them, but I have only added Alamofire to one of the targets in the Pod file so I did not think that this should cause an issue.

Comment: @cnoon I have tried disabling those targets and it doesn't help :(

Comment: I'm strangely getting this same error. I've just updated to the Xcode 7 GM and tried submitting for beta testing, and am unable to do so.

Comment: I was getting same issue.

[This might be solution to your problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this issue is now fixed. I have tried the 2.0.1 version of Alamofire and I am able to submit with Xcode 7 GM and Bit Code turned ON for both Alamofire and my app.