# Invalid Swift Support - Files don’t match

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just re-wrote an app in Swift 2.  I'm trying to upload the app to iTunesConnect (via Xcode 7 GM) for internal testing.

I wrestled with an "Invalid Swift Support" error for awhile ([which has other, related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift)) ... but now it's changed to something a little different.

The error from Apple now says:

**Invalid Swift Support**

The files libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib don’t match

/Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib

***Make sure the files are correct*** (?), rebuild your app, and resubmit it.

Don’t apply post-processing to

/Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib, /Payload/App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

I've been unable to find similar errors by searching for "Don’t apply post-processing", "Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it", etc.

**Does anyone know how I can "Make sure the files are correct" --or-- have any other recommendations?  Thank you.**

Comment: I have exactly same problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you resigning this app? Is this a direct upload from Xcode?

Comment: @Andy direct upload from Xcode immediately after archiving it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Same problem here. I think this is most likely a bug of the Developer Tools, related to the Bitcode.

I just found the workaround for this.

1. Archive your app with new build number :(
2. Find the archive (.xcarchive file) in Finder from Organizer “Show in Finder”
3. Open the package and find directories like `Products/Applications/YourApp.ipa/Frameworks/` and `SwiftSupport/iphoneos/`
4. **Copy** all `libswiftXxx.dylib` files from `SwiftSupport/iphoneos/` into `Products/Applications/YourApp.ipa/Frameworks/` and overwrite
5. Now, *Upload to App Store* from Organizer

With this process, I succeed in uploading my build. Now I’m waiting for review.

NOTE:

I’m using CocoaPods, and the `ENABLE_BITCODE` option was NO.

Comment: What iOS SDK are you targeting?  I thought you couldn't submit to the store with bitcode disabled.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 8 and I was able to submit the app using the workaround above.

Comment: In my case, SwiftSupport/iphoneos/ is empty.

Comment: Validation succeeded for me but the build is still `Processing` after ~12 hours in the Prerelease section of iTunes Connect.

Comment: I'm getting this issue on Xcode 7 final and the above not working.

Comment: I've been failing to get my build up with the Final release of xcode 7. I tried this and managed to get it working sweet! thanks

Comment: hey thanks for this! I'm still getting a warning about API analysis file too large http://cl.ly/image/0s0N0s441s0X -- but the important thing is that it still passed and was able to get into TestFlight.

Comment: In no. 5 "from Organizer" means Application Loader won't work?

Comment: After applying this, the app is taking forever to process... Still "Processing", I'm not sure if it's going to be processed at all !

Comment: This method has stopped working for me, however the answer provided by DJ Tarazona is working now.

Comment: How could you even discover this :)

Comment: What should I do if there is no folder SwiftSupport/iphoneos/ inside my .ipa?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue in tvOS, and in tvOS there is no option of bit code in build option. please provide me proper guidance

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for one of my IPA files.

But for other IPA, got below error. Any suggestions?
"Invalid Swift Support - The file .DS_Store doesn’t have a signing ID. Sign the file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, "

Answer (score 49):

**Edit: [CocoaPods 0.39.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/0.39.0) has been released which fixes this issue!**

As [@orkenstein mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649073/493229), there is [a simpler solution](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188) by commenting out some code in `Pod-frameworks.sh`.  I'm including a bit more details here.

In your Xcode project directory, open `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh`

Comment out the following lines:

```
# Embed linked Swift runtime libraries
local basename
basename="$(basename "$1" | sed -E s/\\..+// && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})"
local swift_runtime_libs
swift_runtime_libs=$(xcrun otool -LX "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/${basename}.framework/${basename}" | grep --color=never @rpath/libswift | sed -E s/@rpath\\/\(.+dylib\).*/\\1/g | uniq -u  && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
for lib in $swift_runtime_libs; do
  echo "rsync -auv \"${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}\" \"${destination}\""
  rsync -auv "${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}" "${destination}"
  code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/${lib}"
done
```

=>

```
# Embed linked Swift runtime libraries
# local basename
# basename="$(basename "$1" | sed -E s/\\..+// && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})"
# local swift_runtime_libs
# swift_runtime_libs=$(xcrun otool -LX "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/${basename}.framework/${basename}" | grep --color=never @rpath/libswift | sed -E s/@rpath\\/\(.+dylib\).*/\\1/g | uniq -u  && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
# for lib in $swift_runtime_libs; do
#   echo "rsync -auv \"${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}\" \"${destination}\""
#   rsync -auv "${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}" "${destination}"
#   code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/${lib}"
# done
```

Save `Pods-frameworks.sh` and you should be good to go!

Comment: This worked for me. Just a heads up, if you run pod-install or pod-update you may have to comment it again!

Comment: Cocoapods issue here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188, you can try this PR: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4221 with those instructions: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/unreleased-features

Comment: updated cocoaPods 0.39.0 and it does not resolve this issue for me

Comment: @DJ Tarazona Thanks for your recipe!! it totally did the trick for me, even when i did update the cocopods gem to the latest version

Answer (score 16):

The fix for this issue has been merged and it is available on the latest CocoaPods version `0.39.0.beta.5`

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4268

To get the latest version of CocoaPods run `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Alternatively, follow instructions for running unreleased features:
http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/unreleased-features

Once you have the latest version of CocoaPods, run `pod install` again.

Comment: This is the money maker

Comment: The tears are coming. Thank you!

Comment: The error doesn't have to do specifically with CocoaPods; we are experiencing the same issue and don't use CocoaPods.

Answer (score 8):

I was using fastlane gym 1.9.0 to build my app and it kept getting rejected by apple because the files didn't match, whereas if i uploaded through XCode 8 it was accepted. I checked the swift libs in the ipa's swift support folder and in the Frameworks folder, I found that the libs in the swift support folder were for swift 2.3 while in the Frameworks folder it was swift 3. So in my gym file I added the toolchain option:

```
gym(
  scheme: "CoCadre", 
  configuration: "Production Release",
  clean: true,
  use_legacy_build_api: false,
  toolchain: "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"
)
```

*Note that i had to change use_legacy_build_api to false to use the toolchain option

> In order to use toolchain option, need to set use_legacy_build_api: false https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6003#issuecomment-244792185

Comment: Thank you! I am also using Fastlane and Gym and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helped to fix the issue when using Gym as well.

Please note that I was still able to use this solution with  use_legacy_build_api: true

Answer (score 6):

There is a little less complex solution, found on [GitHub](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188#issue-106748634):

> I had a look around in *Pods-frameworks.sh* and found a section
>   commented as:
>
> **Embed linked Swift runtime libraries**
>    Commenting the block of code which copies these libraries across (and code signs them) seems to
>   have fixed my submission woes. I've not dived in deeper yet to see if
>   it's just the copying of them which causes the issues or if it's the
>   code-signing. I'm getting a bit out of my depth there.

Answer (score 4):

1. Update your cocoapods to the latest version, type `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal.
2. Run `pod update` under your project's directory.
3. Remember to set **Enable Bitcode** to **NO** for `Debug` option for all your pods.
4. Fixed

The problem is fixed because the following code in `Pods-frameworks.sh`:

```
# Embed linked Swift runtime libraries
local basename
basename="$(basename "$1" | sed -E s/\\..+// && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})"
local swift_runtime_libs
swift_runtime_libs=$(xcrun otool -LX "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/${basename}.framework/${basename}" | grep --color=never @rpath/libswift | sed -E s/@rpath\\/\(.+dylib\).*/\\1/g | uniq -u  && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
for lib in $swift_runtime_libs; do
  echo "rsync -auv \"${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}\" \"${destination}\""
  rsync -auv "${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}" "${destination}"
  code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/${lib}"
done
```

was changed to:

```
# Embed linked Swift runtime libraries. No longer necessary as of Xcode 7.
if [ "${XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR}" -lt 7 ]; then
    local swift_runtime_libs
    swift_runtime_libs=$(xcrun otool -LX "$binary" | grep --color=never @rpath/libswift | sed -E s/@rpath\\/\(.+dylib\).*/\\1/g | uniq -u  && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
  for lib in $swift_runtime_libs; do
    echo "rsync -auv \"${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}\" \"${destination}\""
    rsync -auv "${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}" "${destination}"
    code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/${lib}"
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

My Solution for this:

I'm using Reveal through Cocoapods and Reveal needs to disable Bitcode. So I included Reveal(should work for any other Framwork) only for Debug:

```
pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
```

As my Reveal is now only configured for Debug, I disabled Bitcode only for Debug.

[image]

With this settings everything works fine, without any hacks...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error occur when integrating libraries that do not support bitcode (such as the current stable version of New Relic).  The solution is either to remove the libraries, disable bitcode (and potentially not be able to submit to the store), or wait for updated binaries that support bitcode from your library vender.

Answer (score 0):

The error for me was that i built with Adhoc profile instead of App Store profile for uploading the spa to the app store.