# Invalid Swift Support - Swift 2.0 project for iOS 9, (Xcode build 7A220)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, swift2, testflight, xcode7

My project on Swift 2.0 for iOS 9, (Xcode build 7A220) and I try upload the build to iTunesConnect for TestFlight, but a few minutes after uploading I receive an email:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib don’t match
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib. Make sure
>   the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply
>   post-processing to
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib. Once these
>   issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected
>   binary.

What that means? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Swift Support - Files don’t match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Swift Support / invalid implementation of swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use CocoaPods?

The problem might come from it if you are using Swift pods. To fix it you can edit **Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh** and commenting the block after

```
 # Embed linked Swift runtime libraries
```

More info:

Issue : [github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188](http://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4188)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem. My project was in objective C but when I submitted app to App store through Xcode 7 after successful submission of App, Build was in processing mode and I got email from iTunes that **"Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it."**

**Solution:** In Build setting of your Target Change **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** to **NO**

After this when I submitted Build it get proceed with in 15 minutes. Hope This will help to someone