# Invalid Swift Support--Itunes Connect Error (Swift 2/Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I submitted an app to the app store 3 weeks ago. Then, my target iOS version was 8.4, and I was using Xcode 6.4. After it was submitted, I upgraded to Xcode7. Now, I am trying to submit an update of my app, and I keep getting this message in an email from Apple:

```
   Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftCoreLocation.dylib 
   don’t match /Payload/chemistry.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib. Make sure the
   files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply
   post-processing to /Payload/chemistry.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
```

I have tried to upload 3 builds, and I got the message "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message" in Xcode all 3 times after archiving the app. However, I only got the email above for the first two. I also received a text via the iTunesConnet app saying that my app status had changed to rejected because of an invalid binary for all three builds attempts. For the third try, I tried the solution by DJ Tarazona here: [Invalid Swift Support - Files don’t match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match)

In iTunes Connect, my first 2 build attempts still say "processing", but the third is available to upload. Does this mean that it is acceptable by Apple, regardless of the fact that I received a text saying it had an invalid binary? Would they let me upload a build to iTunesConnect that wasn't valid?

Also, yes, I do have cocoa pods in this project, as well as Parse. I am using no private or undocumented APIs--this app was just fine and accepted just a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

HI i have same problem but our side following some step than submit done:

Project Target >> build setting >> EMBEDDED CONTENT CONTAINS SWIFT = Yes than create new build and submit

PFA Screen shot:

[image: Swift code set yes]

Comment: I tried doing that and still received the same error messages