# Can't submit app for review itunes connect from (12.09.2016)

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

it is from September 12, 2016 I can not do this to send for review of my application. The error specifically is "Could not save the information for your app. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact us."
I spoke by phone apple and tell me that is a problem they have had others and that are working out, but it's been 10 days and I have not heard any more.
The error in the browser console is this:
{"Data": null, "messages": {"warn": null, "error": ["Failure running store submission validations."], "Info": null}, "statusCode": "ERROR"}
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/1152865286/versions/818835542/submit/summary 500 (Internal Server Error)

Does anyone have this problem and solved it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved today. I got a call from Apple developper team saying that the problem had been solved and so I could send for testing my app

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Once I uploaded the build, build getting vanished from iTunes. Even I changed the version number and uploaded the build. But problem exists.
Please tell me, whom I have to contact for this problem.

Comment: This is the link with the telephone number [link]https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/ . You can call assistance. They ask you to send an email with all the screenshot of the problem.
To solve the problem took more 'than a week constantly calling them every day.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks Andrea Antonini :)

Comment: I fixed the issue by using this answer from Stack Overflow. Now the build is appearing in iTunes Connect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32675702/5710152