# The update file (build) disappears in iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I made updating for the app. I load the application through Application Loader 3. Also I loaded directly through xCode 8. After loading, assembly is in the status of "Processing". 5-10 minutes later assembly just disappears. I thought that it is in the hidden processing, and decided to wait. I waited for 12 hours, but assembly did not appear. I filled in already 4 assemblies, all disappear. What's the problem? How to update the app?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JokrH.png)

Comment: I too faced the same issue. I solved that by using the stack overflow answer. Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32675702/5710152
May be it is because of CocoaPods.

Comment: @BoominadhaPrakashM i used Objective-C

Comment: Check whether did administrator receive any email from Apple support to his developer account email. There they have mentioned the problem.