# Invalid Swift Support xcode 8 itunesconnect issue

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, xcode8

I am struggling to get my build uploaded to itunesconnect since upgrading to XCode8 - might have to do with the swift 3.0 syntax update?... i am new to iOS dev, having been doing it now since xcode 7.1....

I submit the through Organizer, the ipa uploads, but then i get an email from itunesconnect:

"Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s Framework location, such as /Payload/Health Storylines.app/Frameworks."

My app target uses obj-c, and the UItest target uses swift.

ive read: [Invalid Swift Support / invalid implementation of swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163856/invalid-swift-support-invalid-implementation-of-swift)

- i cant find any embedded swift settings in xcode8...

ive read:[Invalid Swift Support - Files don’t match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match)

- but in the .sh they want some lines commented out - it only runs on xcode version below 7...show this shouldnt matter.

ive just read http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/

- there are some cocopoads code signing topics in here...not sure if this is relevant?

this the the contects of the .xarchive:
[image]

Im thinking swift need to be turned off somewhere, but dont know where...

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem that I had. Try archiving and exporting the IPA with XCode 7.x.x, and then upload it with Application Loader (XCode 8 GM). Also, what is your macOS version?

Comment: OSX el capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: i could do that, but its not a long term solution, gonna need xcode 8

Comment: This might be a versioning issue with iTunesConnect, not you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue If you are using fastlane and swift 2.3 you may try adding `toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"` on your Gymfile, it worked for me.