# Invalid Swift Support - Doesn't have the correct file type for this location (Swift 2.3 / Xcode 7.3.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The file $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework,

> $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/RxSwift.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Then.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Material.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Realm.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Kingfisher.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/DeviceKit.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/SnapKit.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/XCGLogger.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/PKHUD.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework,
>   $(APP_NAME).app/Frameworks/Whisper.framework doesn’t have the correct
>   file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file,
>   rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and
>   resubmit it.

I received this email after I uploaded my application successfully and I'm not sure what I need to do fix this issue. I didn't upgrade my iOS app to Swift 3.0 due to dependencies and syntax changes. I was wondering if I can still publish a new app to App Store with Xcode 7.3.1.
Does anyone experience this issue? I checked a few posts on StackOverflow regarding Invalid Swift Support, but those are not the same error I am having.

[image: General tab]> [image: Build Settings]

Comment: Are you using Xcode Beta version? because in the error it says "rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version ", if so kindly use GM release of XCode to submit the app.

Comment: I'm running up against the exact same issue as you, except with different pods, using GM Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Tripple check your supported languages. Plus that the info.plist is consistent to the supported languages.

Comment: @chitnisprasanna I'm using GM release of XCode but it's not the latest. I didn't update to 8.1 yet.

Comment: @shallowThought As this will support one language at the moment, I don't have a supported language key in my Info.plist.

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown Did you resolve the issue? I still get this error with GM Xcode 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

At first kindly ensure that you are uploading build with GM version of Xcode and not a beta one.

Follow the steps:

1. Archive your app with new build number :(
2. Find the archive (.xcarchive file) in Finder from Organizer “Show in Finder”
3. Open the package and find directories like Products/Applications/YourApp.ipa/Frameworks/ and SwiftSupport/iphoneos/
4. Copy all Frameworks files from SwiftSupport/iphoneos/ into Products/Applications/YourApp.ipa/Frameworks/ and overwrite
5. Now, Upload to App Store from Organizer

Hope, this will help you!

Comment: The answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match. Unfortunately, this is not the same error. I already tried this but didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: ohh.. Can i get a quick view of build setting page and general page details?

Comment: I've attached a quick view of build setting page and general page.