# Invalid Bundle Structure When Using a Swift Library in a Xamarin app

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to submit an iOS app built using Xamarin that is consuming a Swift library.

I'm trying to use the code here to add the proper Swift support: https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.SwiftSupport but I'm getting the following error when uploading the build:

`ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/SwiftSupport/libswiftCore.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.`

This is quite confusing as I though the whole point was that you need to have the Swift libraries in the Swift support folder?

**Edit:**

My original problem was because I had the `SwiftSupport` folder inside the `Payload` folder but it should be alongside.

Now I get this error when uploading:

`Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftCore.dylib don’t match /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it. Don’t apply post-processing to /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib.`

Comment: Try the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526526/invalid-swift-support-files-don-t-match) to see if it helps.

Comment: I've been able to fix this issue by using the updated script here: https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift/issues/28.