# How to get placemark location data in english if system language is different?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

So, I am using the location manager to get the user location data in Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.

The app supports localization for few languages. I am using the location data to get the user city and country which is then sent to a server to display some info on the Map.

However, if the system language is set to anything other than english, location data is returned in that language, as a result the server is not able to recognise those values.

So, how do I get the placemark location data in english even if the system language is different ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using `CLGeocoder`. Unfortunately, native forward/reverse geocoding on iOS has lots of limitations including inability to select output language. You can also check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331093/clgeocoder-returns-wrong-results-when-city-name-is-equal-to-some-countrys-name) to see some other problems that can arise!

Please have a look at the accepted answer to that question. After reading it I tried Google Maps Geocoding APIs and I can confirm these APIs work great! You can structure advanced queries and you can easily specify the desired output language.